# Text in the table

Tags: tables, text

I have a table which work perfectly fine when I put not a lot of text inside of it, but when I'm trying to add text with a lot of words it's just doesn't display text correctly. I guess I should use \newcolumtype, but I don't know how to use it correctly.

I'm trying to put long text in the row 11 in the second column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, hmargin=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=4cm, headheight=3cm, footskip=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr(\textwidth-5\arrayrulewidth-8\tabcolsep)/4}
\newcommand\sfour{%
\multicolumn{4}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep}|}}
\newcommand\stwol{%
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr2\mylength+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}}
\newcommand\stwor{%
\multicolumn{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr2\mylength+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}
{|*4{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\mylength}|} }
\hline
\stwol{1.Название документа}   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Техническое задание}           \\ \hline
\stwol{2.Компания группы}      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{   }    \\  \hline
\stwol{3.Филиал/подразделение} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  }    \\  \hline
\sfour{4.Вид работ:}   \\ \hline
\sfour{\textbf{    }}  \\ \hline
\sfour{5.Срок поставки, согласно проектного плана}  \\ \hline
\stwol{ }      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  }    \\  \hline
\sfour{6.Перечень разрешительной документации, которая должна быть предоставлена поставщиком: }  \\ \hline
\sfour{  }  \\ \hline
\stwol{7.Необходимость в проведении предварительного аудита поставщика } & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  }    \\  \hline
\stwol{8.Лицо, ответственное за осуществление приемки товара со стороны заказчик } & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{   }    \\  \hline
\stwol{9.Контактное лицо для ответа на технические вопросы} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  }    \\  \hline
\stwol{10.Условия поставки} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  }    \\  \hline
\stwol{11.Описание товаров, которые должны быть поставлены согласно данному техническому заданию:} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  
a. Номинальная грузоподъемность - 1400 кг
b. Грузоподъемность при подъеме мачты - 1000 кг
c. Рабочая высота подъема - 10250 мм
d. Максимальная высота подъема - 10894 мм
}   }    \\  \hline
    \sfour{12.Желаемые приоритеты по порядку выполнения работ: }  \\ \hline
    \sfour{ {{priority}} }  \\ \hline
    \sfour{13.Требования к формированию коммерческого предложения: }  \\ \hline
    \sfour{  }  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, if cyrillc is not needed to represent a problem, please use the latin alphabet.

Comment: Just looking at the table, how many columns does it have?

Comment: Where you like to add more text? in which column? Or in cells, which span all columns?

Comment: your image shows an entry a.....1400 ...... between entries 11 and 12 that is not in the code that you show, please edit the question so that the code and image match and state which entry is causing a problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle just have edited my code.

Comment: @Zarko I'm adding text in the cells which are empty right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you created your own commands, use them.

I am not quite sure why your table is defined by four columns, when obviously you yourself talk about just two.

[image: luckygirlTabular]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, hmargin=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=4cm, headheight=3cm, footskip=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr(\textwidth-5\arrayrulewidth-8\tabcolsep)/4}
\newcommand\sfour{%
    \multicolumn{4}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep}|}}
    \newcommand\stwol{%
        \multicolumn{2}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr2\mylength+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}}
        \newcommand\stwor{%
            \multicolumn{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr2\mylength+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}}

            \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

            \noindent
            \begin{tabular}
                {|*4{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\mylength}|} }
                \hline
                \stwol{1.Название документа}   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Техническое задание}           \\ \hline
                \stwol{2.Компания группы}      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{   }    \\  \hline
                \stwol{3.Филиал/подразделение} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  }    \\  \hline
                \sfour{4.Вид работ:}   \\ \hline
                \sfour{\textbf{    }}  \\ \hline
                \sfour{5.Срок поставки, согласно проектного плана}  \\ \hline
                \stwol{ }      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  }    \\  \hline
                \sfour{6.Перечень разрешительной документации, которая должна быть предоставлена поставщиком: }  \\ \hline
                \sfour{  }  \\ \hline
                \stwol{7.Необходимость в проведении предварительного аудита поставщика } & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  }    \\  \hline
                \stwol{8.Лицо, ответственное за осуществление приемки товара со стороны заказчик } & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{   }    \\  \hline
                \stwol{9.Контактное лицо для ответа на технические вопросы} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  }    \\  \hline
                \stwol{10.Условия поставки} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  }    \\  \hline
                \stwol{11.Описание товаров, которые должны быть поставлены согласно данному техническому заданию:} & \stwol{
                    a. Номинальная грузоподъемность - 1400 кг\newline
                    b. Грузоподъемность при подъеме мачты - 1000 кг\newline
                    c. Рабочая высота подъема - 10250 мм\newline
                    d. Максимальная высота подъема - 10894 мм}    \\  \hline
                \sfour{12.Желаемые приоритеты по порядку выполнения работ: }  \\ \hline
                \sfour{ {{priority}} }  \\ \hline
                \sfour{13.Требования к формированию коммерческого предложения: }  \\ \hline
                \sfour{  }  \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! How to modify \newcommand\sfour  so the long text there doesn't break the table?

Comment: @Lucky_girl Which long text?

Comment: I want to add  text to  \sfour{6.Перечень разрешительной документации, которая должна быть предоставлена поставщиком: }  \\ \hline
  \sfour{ Рич-трак «Double Dip»: Автоматизиро-
ванное устройство с телескопическими ви-
лами для перемещения паллет с грузом
на высоту стеллажного оборудования 10 м
и установленного по методу “Double Dip”
(глубиной одного ряда - 2 паллеты) – 4 шт.  }  \\ \hline

Comment: everything works, I understood my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I suggest to redesign your table. It actually has only two columns, `tabularx` instead of `tabular, then the width of columns are determined by it. Consequently, table become far more simple. See, if this solution can help you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, 
           margin=1in, hmargin=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=4cm, 
           headheight=3cm, footskip=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}% <--- added for better looking of cells content, 

\newcommand\stwo{%<-- adopted 
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}%
                p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for test

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{2}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|}}
                                                        \hline
1.  Название документа      & Техническое задание   \\  \hline
2.  Компания группы         &                       \\  \hline
3.  Филиал/подразделение    &                       \\  \hline
\stwo{4. Вид работ:}                                \\  \hline
    \stwo{\textbf{    }}                            \\  \hline
\stwo{5. Срок поставки, согласно проектного плана}  \\  \hline
                            &                       \\  \hline
\stwo{6. Перечень разрешительной 
         документации, которая должна быть 
         предоставлена поставщиком:}                \\ \hline
    \stwo{\lipsum[2]  }                             \\ \hline
7.  Необходимость в проведении предварительного 
    аудита поставщика       &                       \\  \hline
8.  Лицо, ответственное за осуществление 
    приемки товара со стороны заказчик
                            &                       \\  \hline
9.  Контактное лицо для ответа 
    на технические вопросы  &                       \\  \hline
10. Условия поставки        &                       \\  \hline
11. Описание товаров, которые должны быть 
    поставлены согласно данному 
    техническому заданию:   &   
            a. Номинальная грузоподъемность - 1400 кг       \newline
            b. Грузоподъемность при подъеме мачты - 1000 кг \newline
            c. Рабочая высота подъема - 10250 мм            \newline
            d. Максимальная высота подъема - 10894 мм
                                                    \\  \hline
\stwo{12. Желаемые приоритеты по 
          порядку выполнения работ:}                \\ \hline
    \stwo{priority}                                 \\ \hline
\stwo{13. Требования к формированию 
          коммерческого предложения:}               \\ \hline
    \stwo{ }                                        \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

In one cell I put dummy text from `lipsum` package, that you can see, how it fill by `stwoo` merged cells.
[image]